# Explicite proof that complex power function are holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the function  $f(z):=z^n$ and prove that $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}}f(z)=0$.
Here is my attempt:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
    \dfrac{\partial}{\partial\bar{z}}f(z)&=\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}+i\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)(x+iy)^n=\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}+i\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}x^{n-k}(iy)^k\right)\\
    &=\dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\left[\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(x^{n-k}(iy)^k\right)+i\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(x^{n-k}(iy)^k\right)\right]\\
    &=\dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\left[(n-k)x^{n-k-1}i^ky^k+ki^{k+1}x^{n-k}y^{k-1}\right]\\
    &=\dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\left(i^kx^{n-k-1}y^{k-1}\right)\left[(n-k)y+kix\right].
    \end{split}
\end{equation*}
Now, how can I show that it actually vanishes? Thank you.

Comment: $f(z,\bar z):=z^n$ doesn't depend on $\bar z$, therefore $\partial _{\bar z}f(z,\bar z)=0$.

Comment: @Surb, bruh that's too short.

Comment: Yes, I’m looking for an explicite computation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We obtain
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\frac{\partial}{\partial\overline{z}}z^n}
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+i\,\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)(x+iy)^n\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x+iy)^n
+\frac{i}{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(x+iy)^n\\
&=\frac{1}{2}n(x+iy)^{n-1}+\frac{i}{2}in(x+iy)^{n-1}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=0}
\end{align*}

Comment: Feel so stupid. Thank you very much!

Comment: @GiulioBinosi: You're welcome and nothing to worry about.